# How to properly extend APRegister class in Acumatica

Tags: acumatica

I need to add one bool field to table APPayment. Because APPayment is inherited from APRegister I make extension to class APRegister in the following way:

```
public class APRegisterExt: PXCacheExtension<APRegister>
{

    #region UsrPOAllocated
    public abstract class usrPOAllocated : IBqlField
    {
    }

    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allocated")]
    public bool? UsrPOAllocated{ get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

but then when I navigate to page AP301000, AP302000 I see following error:

Invalid column name 'UsrPOAllocated'.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid column name 'UsrPOAllocated'.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

Stack Trace:

[SqlException (0x80131904): Invalid column name 'UsrPOAllocated'.]
   PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.a(SqlException A_0, IDbCommand A_1) +765
   PX.Data.PXSqlDatabaseProvider.ExecuteReaderInternal(IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior) +357
   PX.Data.PXSelectResultEnumerator.System.Collections.IEnumerator.MoveNext() +473
   PX.Data.PXView.GetResult(Object[] parameters, PXFilterRow[] filters, Boolean reverseOrder, Int32 topCount, PXSearchColumn[] sorts, Boolean& overrideSort, Boolean& extFilter) +6089
   PX.Data.PXView.Select(Object[] currents, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) +2651
   PX.Data.PXGraph.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, Object[] parameters, Object[] searches, String[] sortcolumns, Boolean[] descendings, PXFilterRow[] filters, Int32& startRow, Int32 maximumRows, Int32& totalRows) +1220
   PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.a(Object[] A_0, Object[] A_1, String[] A_2, Boolean[] A_3, PXFilterRow[] A_4, DataSourceSelectArguments A_5) +218
   PX.Web.UI.PXBaseDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) +13726
   PX.Web.UI.PXDataSource.ExecuteSelect(String viewName, DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments pxarguments) +149
   PX.Web.UI.PXDataSourceView.Select(DataSourceSelectArguments arguments, PXDSSelectArguments swarguments, DataSourceViewSelectCallback callback) +65
   PX.Web.UI.PXFormDataProvider.DataBind() +383
   PX.Web.UI.PXBoundPanel.PerformSelect() +135
   System.Web.UI.WebControls.BaseDataBoundControl.EnsureDataBound() +139
   PX.Web.UI.PXDataViewBar.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +33
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +110
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +207
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +2994

So question is, how to correctly extend classes in Acumatica that is base classes for other entities and implement other interfaces?
And one more question. If I extend base class APRegister, then how to reference in grid additional field with possibility to edit? I mean if I extended APRegister but need to display APPayment elements in grid, then how can I show them with edit option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided code snippet seems to work perfectly fine on a brand new Acumatica website once UsrPOAllocated column was added for the APRegister database table:

```
public class APRegisterExt : PXCacheExtension<APRegister>
{
    #region UsrPOAllocated
    public abstract class usrPOAllocated : IBqlField
    {
    }

    [PXDBBool]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Allocated")]
    public bool? UsrPOAllocated { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

[image]

Since APInvoice is inherited from APRegister, for every instance of the APInvoice DAC the framework will always initialize all extensions declared for the base APRegister DAC.

Below is a small sample showing how you can access UsrPOAllocated field declared within the APRegister DAC extension inside RowSelected event handler raised for the APInvoice DAC:

```
public class APInvoiceEntryExt : PXGraphExtension<APInvoiceEntry>
{
    public void APInvoice_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        APInvoice invoice = e.Row as APInvoice;
        if (invoice == null) return;

        var invoiceExt = invoice.GetExtension<APRegisterExt>();
        if (invoiceExt.UsrPOAllocated != true)
        {
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<APInvoice.refNbr>(invoice, invoice.RefNbr,
                new PXSetPropertyException("Document is not allocated", PXErrorLevel.Warning));
        }
        else
        {
            sender.RaiseExceptionHandling<APInvoice.refNbr>(invoice, invoice.RefNbr, null);
        }
    }
}
```

The customization from above was created with layout editor:
[image]

And this is Aspx, that layout editor generated:
`<px:PXCheckBox runat="server" ID="CstPXCheckBox1" DataField="UsrPOAllocated" />`

[image]

Comment: Thanks Ruslan. Just one more clarification, When I asked about access, I meant how to describe in aspx page.

Comment: You are welcome, Yuri. Please see updated answer above.